# Magento 1 - How to update from 1.9.4.4 to 1.9.4.5

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, core

I'm very new to Magento 1 and I need to update from 1.9.4.4 to 1.9.4.5 on my staging system.

How can I do that? I can't use composer or anything else.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest release from Github. Then just overwrite your Magento files. Make sure to not overwrite your config.xml.
https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/releases/tag/1.9.4.5

Or just use the latest LTS version as it’s more secure and it supports PHP 7.4.X.